# Download file which was upload to mysql to server directory

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched and searched but have not found a script capable of downloading files which are uploaded to my mysql database down to a directory in my server.
This is only temporary and once the file has been used it'll need to be disposed of.
Got any ideas?

Comment: How are you uploading a file to a MySQL database? Do you mean you're storing the file contents as a binary column?

Comment: Yes, I am, also in the table it has the size and mime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you meant that the file is saved into mysql database like BLOB (binary data)

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tablename where id=XXXX");
     if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
     $r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
     file_put_contents($filename,$r['column_blob']);  
   }
```

I used [file_put_contents](http://it.php.net/file_put_contents) function that it is binary safe, but there is also [fwrite](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)